# Opening/reading a list of unknown files using I/O methods

Tags: python, methods, io

So I'm a newb :) Python question

I have a list of files and I'm looking to open/read these files using an I/O method

I understand if I explicitly go through each test file I've created and opening them one by one would be fine but how about if I have an unknown file and I tell it to be open/read, how would this be done?

Logically thinking, it sounds like I need to create a variable and assign it to a list of files and from there tell it open all the files in the list. So a for loop perhaps?

Comment: Can you be specific? what language are you planning to use ? Better if you can include some code that you have written so far.

Comment: @brokenfoot sorry about that, python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import os
for fl in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    with open(fl) as f:
        #do stuff
```

Alternatively, if your files are not in the same directory as your script, you can do:

```
for fl in os.listdir('custom/path/to/files'):
```

Comment: @BIGROB1212, Glad I could help. Not exactly my forte :)